# Loading Divs randomly with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, random

I'm battling to get what seems like a reasonable simple script functioning which I'd like to randomise seven Divs on browser refresh with.

The HTML appears as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<title>Strict</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
    }).slice(0,4)
    $(divs).show();
 </script>

</head>

<body>


<div class="Image"><img src="image1.jpg">1</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image2.jpg">2</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image3.jpg">3</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image4.jpg">4</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image5.jpg">5</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image6.jpg">6</div>
<div class="Image"><img src="image7.jpg">7</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The jQuery script in there should be:

```
var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
}).slice(0,4)
$(divs).show();
```

CSS is limited to:

```
div.Image {
display: none;
}
```

Nothing is loading at all, currently.

I'm still brand new to this, so i will have to excuse myself if this is elementary.

Answer (score 2):

Please wrap your code inside `document.ready`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function()
    {
       return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
    }).slice(0,4);

    $(divs).show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Surround the function with [$(document).ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so it loads after the page is completely loaded.  The `div` elements have not been loaded on the page at the time when your script executes.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
    }).slice(0,4)
    $(divs).show();
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FyzXF/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
   var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
                 return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
              }).slice(0,4)
   $(divs).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to wrap your js code into a `$(function(){ ... })` block:

```
$(function(){

    var divs = $("div.Image").get().sort(function(){ 
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5; //random so we get the right +/- combo
    }).slice(0,4)
    $(divs).show();

});
```

This means that your code is executed when DOM is full loaded.

Comment: Great stuff folks, thank you for all the info! I believe it was the script loading prior to the images.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. Try this

```
$(function(){
  var ind = Math.floor((Math.random()*7)+1);
  $("div.Image:eq("+ind+")").show();
});
```